# SSRS to use a java runtime to decrypt to display the data?

Tags: java, encryption, reporting-services, runtime, reporting

I just need some advice…

I got asked about using Java runtime with SSRS. I'm a novice at java but willing to learn what it takes to achieve this (if possible at all) I'm quite knowledgeable in MS BI Stack

We have a system that is java based and they are capturing bank account numbers / codes on the screens. This will be written into the database using a java runtime that will encrypt the data. When the application needs to display it on the screen the same runtime will decrypt it.

The same information is required on a SSRS report hence the question, can SSRS use a java runtime decrypt to display the data?

anyone come across this

Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you can't use your Java runtime directly as a data source for a SSRS report, however there are some ways you can do this indirectly, the first one is to use a proxy format that is understod by SSRS, it can be [XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or [JSON](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/), on this case, you will make your Java runtime to output any of these formats and feed it into the report;
the second one is to use a [CLR Stored Procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx), this way you'll need to recreate part of your Java runtime into .NET and create a CLR Stored Procedure that will serve as the data source of your SSRS report.

Every approach have it's pros and cons, but i would pick recreating part of the Java runtime as a CLR Stored Procedure, given that is the most robust way to do what you want to do.